# How i can click the anchor tag that matches the specified text in codeception

Tags: php, codeception

In the **codeception**, how to click on link of anchor tag using "textadded"

```
<a class="edit" href="https://abcd.em/123">textadded</a>


`$I->click(".edit [textadded]");` //just for the example
```

Answer (score 0):

For "click" you can just use verbose text:

```
<a class="edit" href="https://abcd.em/123">textadded</a>


`$I->click("textadded");` //just for the example
```